# Authorize.net payment gateway... few questions

Tags: ecommerce, payments, authorize.net

I need a good payment gateway for my shop (Drupal Ubercart).

I was considering to use Authorize.net... is it available in Europe ?

My customer has revenues of 10.000 per week so I'm looking for a professional solution.

Could you give me some tip ?

thanks

Comment: Hi,

I was wondering if anyone knows whether it's already possible to use Authorize.not gateway with EU merchant account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not available in Europe. It is only available for US based merchant accounts. You can take European credit cards through Authorize.Net but only if you have a US merchant account.

From their FAQ

> At this time, we are only able to offer our services to U.S. based businesses, or merchants who have U.S. based merchant accounts.

Comment: ok thanks. So, is there any similar payment gateway in Europe ?

Comment: Things work different in the US then the rest of the world. You may want to check out WorldPay.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [PayPal Website Payments Pro](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/compare_wp_products). It's essentially the same cost as Auth.NET, but it may be available in Europe.